# Why is my random number generator from a new array not working? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am making a card game but right now I am having a problem with the random number generator. I am creating new array with 100 choices and then randomly selecting a number from that array. However, when I document.write correctNum, I am getting undefined.

```
var numList = new Array(100);

var correctNum = numList[Math.floor(Math.random()*numList.length)];

document.write(correctNum);
```

Comment: You are not generating a random number array because you're not filling the array, just accessing a random index which would be undefined because you haven't filled the array...

Answer (score 1):

You must fill the array with something. All you are doing is declaring its size and since arrays in JavaScript are dynamic (that is, their size can grow and shrink after they've been created), it's not that useful to pre-declare a size anyway:

```js
var numList = [];

// Fill the array with numbers from 0 to 99
for(var i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
   numList.push(i);
}

var correctNum = numList[Math.floor(Math.random()*numList.length)];

// Don't use document.write. It will wipe out the existing document in 
// favor of the new content. Either write the to the console (for debugging)
// or inject data into pre-existing element that's already on the page
console.log(correctNum);
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I was misinterpreting what exactly the new Array was doing.

Answer (score 0):

The array numList contains 100 undefined. Once you populate the array with the real data, the rest of the logic will give you what you want.

do for example:

```
for(var i=0; i<numList.length; i++){
    numList.push(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Array(100)` returns array with 100 undefined elements.

```js
var numList = new Array(100);
console.log(numList);
```

You have to fill it or just make an array containing the numbers you like, if you want to get a random number from it.

```js
var numList = Array.apply(null, {length: 100}).map(Number.call, Number);

var correctNum = numList[Math.floor(Math.random()*numList.length)];

document.write(correctNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your array is currently empty, I would recommend filling it with whatever numbers you would like. Another solution, if you just want to pick a random number from 1-100, you code use this code below, which will return a random number in between 1 and 100.

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
```

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your array is still empty. 
By using constructor `arr = new Array(<integer>)` it gets only length but no values at indexes.

```
var arr = new Array(100);
console.log(arr.length); // 100
console.log(arr[1]); // undefined
```